# How to Differentiate whether the request is un-authenticate or session time out

Tags: session, servlets, jakarta-ee, basic-authentication, http-authentication

I have J2EE web application with basic HTTP authentication implementation deploying on glassfish server. Added a session time out in web.xml for 30 minutes.

- *Now when ever session time out happened, server sends back the status code 401 to client browser which shows the basic auth popup and*
- *even the same behavior observed when any rest call is fired outside the application (postman or direct api call from browser ex: any get request or post request from browser).*

Now i want to differentiate those 2 different behavior calls on the server. Here there are 2 different scenario .

1. **session time out**
2. **request is un-authenticated**

   But don't no how to differentiate those call. Appreciate any suggestions or thoughts on this?

Note:*Here i have implemented HTTP basic authentication which handles the authentication mechanism*

Comment: This is the different question.. here i am facing difficulty to differentiate those calls on the server...and also i am not using jsp here..

Comment: can i do some think on the server side to handle those request  and remember i am using http basic authentication mechanism